# Multi-threading Java how to make thread to wait some time

Tags: java, multithreading

> **Parking Problem**
>
> There's n parking lots. On one parking lot, there can be only one car at a time. If all parking lots are occupied then the car will wait some time and if there's still no free parking lot then it leaves.

It needs to be solved using threads (synchronized by will).

Here's my code:

**Parking**

```
class Parking implements Runnable {
private Thread thread;
private String threadName;
static int parkingLots;

static {
    parkingLots = 5;
}

Parking(String threadName) {
    this.threadName = threadName;
}

public void run() {
    if (parkingLots > 0) {
        long restTime = (long) (Math.random() * 2000);
        try {
            parkingLots--;
            System.out.println("Car " + threadName + " stands in the parking lot");
            Thread.sleep(restTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        parkingLots++;
        System.out.println("Car " + threadName + " has left parking, it stood there" + ((double)restTime / (double)1000) + " s");
    } else
        System.out.println("Car " + threadName + " has left parking");
}

public void start() {
    if (thread == null) {
        thread = new Thread(this, threadName);
        thread.start();
    }
}
}
```

**Main**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Parking> parking = new ArrayList<Parking>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            parking.add(new Parking(String.valueOf(i + 1)));
        }
        for (Parking i: parking) {
            i.start();
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to see (when there are 2 parking lots and 4 cars):

```
Car 1 stands in the parking lot
Car 2 stands in the parking lot
Car 3 is waiting
Car 4 is waiting
Car 3 has left parking
Car 2 has left parking, it stood there 1.08 s
Car 4 stands in the parking lot
Car 1 has left parking, it stood there 1.71 s
Car 4 has left parking, it stood there 0.83 s
```

But what I get (when there are 2 parking lots and 4 cars): all first cars (1 and 2) standing in the parking and the others (3 and 4) just left it, because there are no free parking lots. Even if there's like 15 cars they still can't get in there.

So how can I make for cars to wait some time before leaving? If there's free parking lot then they will go for it else they gonna left parking.

Comment: you are not using synchronization, you should use a Lock object, and some Condition variables to implement this the right way, this code needs some serious refactoring to be done in the right way

Comment: Don't place a `Thread` inside a `Runnable`. It should be the other way around. Think of the primary class as a coordinator; it will manage the details of threads and instantiation for `ParkingLot` and `Car` types, each of which would have a `Runnable#run` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified your code, see if this works.

```
public class Parking implements Runnable {
    private Thread thread;
    private String threadName;
    static int parkingLots;

    static {
        parkingLots = 5;
    }

    Parking(String threadName) {
        this.threadName = threadName;
    }

    public void run() {
        long restTime = (long) (Math.random() * 2000);
        if (parkingLots > 0) {
            checkparking();
        } else {
            try {
                System.out.println("Car " + threadName + " is waiting");
                Thread.sleep(restTime);
                System.out.println("Car " + threadName + " is checking for free parkinglot");
                checkparking();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public void checkparking() {
        if (parkingLots > 0) {
        long restTime = (long) (Math.random() * 2000);
        try {
            parkingLots--;
            System.out.println("Car " + threadName + " stands in the parking lot");
            Thread.sleep(restTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        parkingLots++;
        System.out.println(
                "Car " + threadName + " has left parking, it stood there" + ((double) restTime / (double) 1000) + " s");

    } else {
        System.out.println(
                "Car " + threadName + " has left since there is no parking space");
    }
    }

    public void start() {
        if (thread == null) {
            thread = new Thread(this, threadName);
            thread.start();
        }
    }

}
```

public class Main {

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
            ArrayList<Parking> parking = new ArrayList<Parking>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                parking.add(new Parking(String.valueOf(i + 1)));
            }
            for (Parking i: parking) {
                i.start();
            }
        }
}
```

output :

```
Car 2 stands in the parking lot
Car 1 stands in the parking lot
Car 7 is waiting
Car 5 stands in the parking lot
Car 3 stands in the parking lot
Car 6 is waiting
Car 4 stands in the parking lot
Car 9 is waiting
Car 8 is waiting
Car 10 is waiting
Car 11 is waiting
Car 12 is waiting
Car 13 is waiting
Car 14 is waiting
Car 15 is waiting
Car 4 has left parking, it stood there0.049 s
Car 14 is checking for free parkinglot
Car 14 stands in the parking lot
Car 5 has left parking, it stood there0.366 s
Car 2 has left parking, it stood there0.461 s
Car 12 is checking for free parkinglot
Car 12 stands in the parking lot
Car 15 is checking for free parkinglot
Car 15 stands in the parking lot
Car 1 has left parking, it stood there0.882 s
Car 9 is checking for free parkinglot
Car 9 stands in the parking lot
Car 10 is checking for free parkinglot
Car 10 has left since there is no parking space
Car 3 has left parking, it stood there1.014 s
Car 13 is checking for free parkinglot
Car 13 stands in the parking lot
Car 15 has left parking, it stood there0.937 s
Car 6 is checking for free parkinglot
Car 6 stands in the parking lot
Car 11 is checking for free parkinglot
Car 11 has left since there is no parking space
Car 13 has left parking, it stood there0.344 s
Car 7 is checking for free parkinglot
Car 7 stands in the parking lot
Car 8 is checking for free parkinglot
Car 8 has left since there is no parking space
Car 7 has left parking, it stood there0.054 s
Car 14 has left parking, it stood there1.731 s
Car 9 has left parking, it stood there1.359 s
Car 12 has left parking, it stood there1.877 s
Car 6 has left parking, it stood there1.787 s
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using and synchronization, your class shouldn't implement Runnable and the semantics you are using are not correct.

For example, after start cars can't park/leave, and multithreading is about something being accessed by multiple threads at the same time and not leading to inconsistent state, in your case you are basically just creating threads and doing something.

Your structure should be something like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Parking  {

    private final Lock monitor = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition lotAvailable = monitor.newCondition();

    private List<Car> parkedCars = new ArrayList<>();

    private final int maxCapacity;
    private int occupied;

    public Parking(int maxCapacity) {
        this.maxCapacity = maxCapacity;
    }

    private boolean tryPark(Car car, int maxWaitingMillis) throws InterruptedException{
        try {
            monitor.lock();
            if(occupied >= maxCapacity){
                long nanos = lotAvailable.awaitNanos(maxWaitingMillis);
                while (occupied >= maxCapacity) {
                    if (nanos <= 0L)
                        return false;
                    nanos = lotAvailable.awaitNanos(nanos);
                }
                ++occupied;
                parkedCars.add(car);
                return true;
            }
            ++occupied;
            parkedCars.add(car);
            return true;
        }catch (InterruptedException ie){
            System.out.println(ie.getMessage());
            throw ie;
        }finally {
            monitor.unlock();
        }

    }

    private void leave(Car car){
        try {
            monitor.lock();
            if(parkedCars.remove(car)) {
                --occupied;
                lotAvailable.signal();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }finally {
            monitor.unlock();
        }
    }


}
```